# What is the correct usage of Collections.max()?

Tags: java, arrays

To my understanding the `Collections.max` method implements a loop to determine the greatest value of an array.

However, for some reason it does not return the greatest value for me, instead returning the first value. I've tried this with multiple data sets but I keep getting the same result.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
int inputNum;
ArrayList<Integer> total = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set4 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set5 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set6 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set7 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set8 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> set9 = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("Please enter the values of your dataset"
    + " (between 1-50. Once you are done filling it in,"
    + " please type any number greater than 51.");

do {
    // Sort the values here
    inputNum = input.nextInt();
    if (6 > inputNum) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set1.add(inputNum);
    } else if (11 > inputNum && inputNum > 5) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set1.add(inputNum);
    } else if (11 > inputNum && inputNum > 5) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set2.add(inputNum);
    } else if (16 > inputNum && inputNum > 10) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set3.add(inputNum);
    } else if (21 > inputNum && inputNum > 15) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set4.add(inputNum);
    } else if (26 > inputNum && inputNum > 20) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set4.add(inputNum);
    } else if (31 > inputNum && inputNum > 25) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set5.add(inputNum);
    } else if (36 > inputNum && inputNum > 30) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set6.add(inputNum);
    } else if (41 > inputNum && inputNum > 35) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set7.add(inputNum);
    } else if (46 > inputNum && inputNum > 40) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set8.add(inputNum);
    } else if (51 > inputNum && inputNum > 45) {
        total.add(inputNum);
        set9.add(inputNum);
    }
} while (51 > inputNum);

//find average, maximum, range, median, histogram
int sum = 0;
for (double i : total)
    sum += i;
System.out.println("sum total of dataset: "+ sum);

double sizeTotal = total.size();
System.out.println("number of data points entered: " + sizeTotal);

double average = sum / sizeTotal;
System.out.println("The average value of your data is: " + average);

//maximum
Collections.max(total);
System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + total.get(0));
```

Comment: `Collections.max()` does not sort the collection - use the return value from max()

Comment: Unrelated, but I find even this simple code difficult to read and reason about. It's partially the formatting and indentation (and lack thereof), partially the (relatively) unusual expression ordering.

Comment: For future questions please create a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". You can read more on this here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jontro you can shortcut link to that by typing `[mvce]`

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks, didn't know about that :)

Comment: Your question lacks a bit of research effort. Please, before asking at SO, at least check the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) of your method and do some quick web searches. Otherwise you get down-votes.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the last line to:

```
System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + Collections.max(total));
```

And you will get the right result.

`Collections.max(total)` does not sort / change the collection. It simply returns the maximum value.

Here is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: See explanation about how `Collections.max` works in the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.max() does not return sorted collection.
If you want max value in list, modify your code as

```
Integer highest = Collections.max(total);
System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go nice and clean. 
`Collection.max()` returns the maximum value, `total.get(0)` will still give you the value you stored at the very beginning.

You can see a nice implementation of the same [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_max_comparator.htm).

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int inputNum;
        ArrayList<Integer> total= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set1= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set3= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set4= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set5= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set6= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set7= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set8= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> set9= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Please enter the values of your dataset (between 1-50. Once you are done filling it in, please type any number greater than 51.");
        do {
        //sort the values here
        inputNum = input.nextInt();
        if (6 > inputNum){
        total.add(inputNum);
        set1.add(inputNum);
        }
        else if (11 > inputNum ){ // obviously it is greater than 5 otherwise it won't come to the else part.
        total.add(inputNum);
        set1.add(inputNum);
        }
        else if (11 > inputNum ){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set2.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (16 > inputNum ){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set3.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (21 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set4.add(inputNum);
        }
        else if (26 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set4.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (31 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set5.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (36 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set6.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (41 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set7.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (46 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set8.add(inputNum);
            }
        else if (51 > inputNum){
            total.add(inputNum);
            set9.add(inputNum);
            }
        }
        while (51 > inputNum);
        //find average, maximum, range, median, histogram
        //average
        int sum = 0;
        for (double i : total)
            sum += i;
        System.out.println("sum total of dataset: "+ sum);
        double sizeTotal = total.size();
        System.out.println("number of data points entered: " + sizeTotal);
        double average = sum / sizeTotal;
        System.out.println("The average value of your data is: " + average);
        //=======
        //maximum
        int max = Collections.max(total);
        System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + max);
    }
}
```

Stdin input:

```
3 8 13 18 28 58
```

Output:

```
Please enter the values of your dataset (between 1-50. Once you are done filling it in, please type any number greater than 51.
sum total of dataset: 70
number of data points entered: 5.0
The average value of your data is: 14.0
The highest value in the array is: 28
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The method `Collections#max` does **not sort** your collection. It **finds** and returns the maximum value.

To quote from its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-):

> Returns the **maximum element** of the given collection, according to the **natural ordering** of its elements.

And very important:

> This method **iterates over the entire collection**, hence it requires time proportional to the size of the collection.

So the operation is **not** *fast*. If performance does matter you may memorize and update the maximum value at the point where the collection is built.

---

Let's now take a look at your current code:

```
Collections.max(total);
System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + total.get(0));
```

Your call `Collections.max(total)` correctly computes and returns the maximum value, however you are **not catching** the **return value**, you simply **throw it away**.

The call to `total.get(0)` correctly returns the **first element** in your collection. But as `Collections#max` did not change anything in the order, this element will still be the same, potentially **not the maximum value**.

---

### Solution

Instead of assuming that the method sorts the collection you can simply **use its return value** which is the maximum value you are searching:

```
int maxValue = Collections.max(total);
System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + maxValue);
```

Or without storing the value in a variable:

```
System.out.println("The highest value in the array is: " + Collections.max(total));
```